# Conditional inline style in react js

Tags: reactjs, css, material-ui

I want to hide the button if **this.state.task.status == 'Completed'**(Like adding display: none property)

**Code:**

```
<Button size="small"           
style={{display:this.state.task.status == "Completed" ? "none":""}}              
style={textColor} >Mark as Completed</Button>
```

**textColor** is another style which is working fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only want to pass a single `style` prop to a component. By passing two, the second one is overriding the first one, causing your `display` style to never make it to the styles:

```
<Button
  size="small"           
  style={{
    display: this.state.task.status == "Completed" ? "none": "",
    textColor,
  }}              
>
  Mark as Completed
</Button>
```

I support @MRchief's answer as well: in React, if you don't want to show an element, you shouldn't render it, unless you specifically need it hidden on the page for some reason (such as a hidden input).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<div>
{ this.state.task.status == "Completed" && (<Button size="small" style={textColor} >Mark as Completed</Button>) }
</div>
```