# Adding style conditionally to a React component

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to add an inline style prop to a React component using the following:

```
<div className="items" ref={containerRef} style={max_width !== '0px' && { maxWidth: max_width }}>
```

Where `max_width` is a string var and `containerRef` is a reference from an `useRef` hook. But, adding the style attribute throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.current is null
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the syntax I used correct?

Comment: Not entirely sure how inline style can be connected to the ref error, but I think `style` prop can't have a `false` value. It should allow `null` so maybe make it use `null` value instead of `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of apply a condition for styling is this

```
<div className="items" ref={containerRef} style={{ maxWidth: max_width !== '0px' ? max_width : '' }}>
```

Make sure `style` value has double open/closed curly braces like an object `{{ }}`.

You can find more informations here:

[Conditional inline style in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727021/conditional-inline-style-in-react-js)

https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp